# Does it really matter to keep a .css fallback for less.js for production?

Tags: css, usability, less

I am getting into less.js, for development and production on client sites. It's amazing how it can extend CSS, and for me there isn't really that much difference in speed when using it.

I'm wondering if it's really that important to keep a .css fallback file for less.js? I'm sure if a user is browsing without JavaScript enabled, then they wouldn't really be able to browse much other sites anyways.  What do you think? Does it really matter?

Some say it's not mean't for production, but is that true?

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question so it doesn't get closed.  For example, "Does it really matter" to "What are possible problems?", or whatever you want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using less I suggest you precompile your less files into CSS files.  Relying on less to parse your css files on the client side is introducing another point of failure.

On their website http://lesscss.org/ there are plenty of examples of how to do this.

If your using .NET you can use [T4 Templates](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/01/t4-template-for-less-css.aspx) or you can use [DotLess](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) which uses an httphandler to compile the less file on the fly server side.

Comment: Yeah I could, if I knew I wasn't going to edit the css after to just compile and paste it in. But in most cases the css will need to be changed, so editing to files just seems a bit to much.

Comment: Still, if you want fallback, you need to do it like that. `less.js` is meant for development no for production. For production compile it.

Comment: I second that - always compile to CSS for production.